# TextBox alignment is not set when it loaded inside the contentcontrol

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have loaded a TextBox inside the content control. i have set few properties to textbox as shown in below.

```
 <ContentControl Width="500" Height="300" Background="Red" >
        <TextBox Width="200" Height="100"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="textbox"/>
 </ContentControl>
```

but HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment is set for Textbox and not for TextBoxView in TextBox control. so that in view my style is not loaded.

Any help!!!

Comment: what do you mean in "TextBoxView"

Comment: MS TextBox control :TextBox->Border->TextBoxView

Comment: if you mean the **Text** Inside the TextBox you should use `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment`

Comment: You can also play around the Padding also..

Comment: @safi yes am trying to set the HorizontatlContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment for text inside the textbox